# python set a dictionnary from lines

Tags: python, dictionary, subprocess

from a specific subprocess command, i got this output (stdout) bellow:

```
cmd = 'xx_cmd'
print(subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True).communicate()[0].decode('utf-8').strip())
```

i search a way to set this output under a dictionnay:

stdout:

```
Series# : 123456
diskid : 7788
type_disk : nvme
cap(mo) : 5685
disk_attr : ssd : link : mapped
```

I search to set the dictionnary as follow:

```
['Series#':'123456','diskid':'7788','type_disk':'nvme','cap(mo)':'5685','disk_attr': ['ssd','link','mapped']]
```

Many thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a dictionary comprehension to get the data you want

```py
inp = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True).communicate()[0].decode('utf-8').strip()

data = {
    key: (values if len(values) > 1 else values[0])
    for key, *values in [line.split(" : ") for line in inp.splitlines()]
}
```

```py
{'Series#': '123456', 'diskid': '7788', 'type_disk': 'nvme', 'cap(mo)': '5685', 'disk_attr': ['ssd', 'link', 'mapped']}
```

for simple testing, you can set the `inp` (short for "input", but `input` is already a builtin function. you can rename it to whatever you want, though)

```py
inp = """\
Series# : 123456
diskid : 7788
type_disk : nvme
cap(mo) : 5685
disk_attr : ssd : link : mapped"""
```

Comment: many thanks for you help. i can use the dict data!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps not the sexiest solution, but try this:

```
stdout = 'Series# : 123456\ndiskid : 7788\ntype_disk : nvme\ncap(mo) : 5685\ndisk_attr : ssd : link : mapped'
res = {}

for l in stdout.split('\n'):
    k, v = l.split(' : ', 1)
    v = v.split(' : ')

    if len(v) == 1:
        v = v[0]

    res[k] = v
```

produces:

```
    In [9]: res
    Out[9]:
    {'Series#': '123456',
     'diskid': '7788',
     'type_disk': 'nvme',
     'cap(mo)': '5685',
     'disk_attr': ['ssd', 'link', 'mapped']}
```